# Is there a reason that Apple's USB vendor ID on Linux is a close anagram of Broadcom's?

Tags: linux, usb

I was poking around in `lsusb` and I noticed that Apple's USB vendor ID, `05ac`, is a very close anagram of Broadcom's, `0a5c`. Is there a historical/political/other reason for this, or is it just a coincedence?

Answer (score 2):

Magic numbers (or in this case, identifiers) are most of the time random, through sometimes funny (think [hexadecimal DEADBEEF](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=deadbeef)). These numbers could or couldn't be incidental, but there's no reason why they would want to be "close anagram" of anything. I would brush off as mere coincidence.